# MEAN stack: To Store image file in mongodb by form data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am having trouble in storing image file in mongodb, 
how can we store files in mongodb??

I am making a MEAN shop app and having issue in storing product image file in db.

getting the error

`typeError: cannot read the property 'productimage' of undefined`

here is the addproduct function

```js
function addProduct(req, res, next){
    var newProduct = new Product({
        productName: req.body.productname,
        productCategory: req.body.productcategory,
        productDescription: req.body.productdescription,
        productPrice: req.body.productprice
        });
    
    newProduct.productImage.data = fs.readFileSync(req.file.productimage);
    newProduct.productImage.contentType = 'jpg';
    
     newProduct.save(function(err){
            if(err){ 
                console.log("error saving product");
                res.status(400).json({ 
                    success: false, 
                    message:'Error processing request '+ err});
        }
        else{
            console.log("product inserted");
            res.status(201).json({
                success: true,
  message: 'Product added successfully.'
        });
    }
    });
}
module.exports = {addProduct);
```

here is the product model,

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const productSchema = new Schema({
  productName : { type: String },
  productCategory: { type: String },
  productDescription: { type: String },
  productImage: { data: Buffer, contentType: String },
  productPrice: { type: Number }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('product', productSchema, 'products');
```

here is the html

```html
<form class="form-style-9" 
       [formGroup]="productForm"
      (ngSubmit)="addProduct(productForm.value)"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      >
    <ul>
        <li><span>Product Name</span>
            <input type="text" name="productname" class="field-style field-full align-none" placeholder="Name" formControlName="productname" />
        </li>
        <span>Product Category</span><br>
        <select formControlName="productcategory">
          <option value="Clothing">Clothing</option>
          <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
          <option value="Books">Books</option>
          <option value="Toys">Toys</option>
        </select>
        <li><span>Product Description</span>
            <textarea name="productdescription" class="field-style" placeholder="Product Description" formControlName="productdescription"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li><span>Product Image</span>
            <input type="file" name="productimage" class="field-style field-full align-none" placeholder="Image" formControlName="productimage"/>
        </li>
        <li><span>Product Price</span>
            <input type="number" name="productprice" class="field-style field-full align-none" placeholder="Product Price" formControlName="productprice" />
        </li>
        <li>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Product" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

How can i store image in mongodb or there is any other way to store product image ? so that we can retrieve it later.

Comment: What middleware are you using to parse the requests? body-parser? multer?

Comment: yes bodyparser and multer too.

Comment: `var multer = require('multer');

var app = express();

var api = require('./server/routes/api');
var image = multer({ dest:'./server/public/' });

app.post('/product', image.single('images'), api.addProduct);`

Comment: content type  should be   newProduct.productImage.contentType = 'image/jpg';

Comment: @dev9 yes edited it but still same error.